# Ajax JS returns object correctly, yet properties within are undefined in console.log

Tags: javascript, ajax

AJAX request get data from DB in PHP, returns data as a JSON.encoded object  - shown like this in console.log..

```
{"id":"117069","cvf":"70710900","cve":"70710910","cpf":"70710900","cpe":"70710910"}
```

When I try to add data.id to a variable and console.log this new variable, it shows as undefined.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use the `parseJSON()` method to convert a json string to a json object?

Comment: No, in my PHP treatment file I used ... echo json_encode($SelectedData);

Comment: The server response to ajax javascript is the string json. In order to work with this json string using javascript as a javascript object, you need to convert this string to an object on the JavaScript side using `parseJSON()`.  @James Ross Codes

Comment: Thank you - that's what was missing.